# Why are emails not updating on my iPad but are on my iPhone

Tags: ipad

My emails are not updating on the iPad. They are ok on iPhone and on my pc. I have tried resetting, deleting account on iPad, turning on and off, resting broadband, nothing works.

Comment: Can you still send email from your iPad? What kind of account is it, iCloud, Google or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Just had exactly the same problem ... BT mail worked fine on my iPhone and PC but NOT on the iPad.   Solved the issue by simply deleting the 'Mail' app and reinstating from the app store .. re-entered email and password and away it went fine.  I can only assume that there may have been a corruption in the iPad mail app.

Answer (score -1):

I had same thing tried everything, deleting accounts, adding again, turning off ipad numerous times. I had open email on safari.i went back in and open the email again on safari and the actually logged out before X out. This worked for my app and everything updated.

Comment: Thanks Lisa, that suggestion worked for me. I logged out of the mail app on my ipoad and ensured it was not running. Went to Safari, logged into iCloud mail and back out, and closed Safari. Restarted my iPad and everything was back to normal. I did not need to delete anything!